# SQL Server login failed in Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, windows-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have a problem to login to SQL Server 2014 Express edition using a SQL Server user.

I have this problem in Windows Server 2012. In normal Windows machine I can create user and login. I changed the authentication mode to mix and did the all thing in Internet but still I got login error.

> Error Number: 18456
>   Severity: 14
>   State: 1
>   Line Number: 65536

If anyone can please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was conflict with previous installation instant. After I remove everything and reinstall SQL again make it work.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to connect? Is there any connection string? And Do you check connectting with `udl` file.

For testing with `udl` file follow below:

1. Create a new `txt` file.
2. Change its extension to `udl`.
3. Run it.
4. Select `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` in `Provider` tab.
5. Enter your entries.

Service of `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` must be started in your services.

If `udl` file works, I think you need to reinstall SQL Server. <sub>[from comment]</sub>

Comment: Ok!, But if you can test your connection via a `udl` file, plz!. It will shows that the MSSQLSERVER service is running.

Comment: I did check the connection with udl file. In normal windows connection its working and in server its not connecting and inside the file same detail saved only the server name is difference

Comment: If the server is the own sql-server try `.` and `127.0.0.1` and IP of server as server name. all of them should answered.