# Can't connect to SQL Server from Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am trying to connect from Crystal Reports 2013 to my local Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database engine.

I believe I've tried all possibilities.

For drivers: `OLE DB (ADO)/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server; Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider; SQL Server Native Client 11.0`. For authentication: for server: `.; .\Local; (local); myserver name`. For integrated mode: `checked and unchecked`.

The only general comment I got from the CR is: Login failed for the user 'my user name'
I am quite sure about a password however when I connect to SQL Server from Management Studio with selected Windows Authentication mode it doesn't require to give a password.

Could it be something other then wrong password that block my connection?

Comment: Have you tried to create a [UDL file to check the connection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28925271/4519059)? ;).

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: The login may be a SQL Server login but the server only accepts Windows Authentication

Resolution :

[image]

Case 2: You are trying to connect by using SQL Server Authentication but the login used does not exist on SQL Server

Resolution : [Create a Login](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)

Comment: 1. checked but no result in CR; 2. the login exists

Comment: Can you try same login in SSMS?

Comment: But you said u used windows authentication in SSMS. did it worked with SQL Server authentication like 'username' and 'password' ?

Comment: No, I login only with windows authentication. It seems that I cant connect via Server authentication (Ive created new login, and try it via managment studion with no result). I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78317/discussion-between-arth81-and-pravin-deshmukh).

Comment: Did you install both a 64 bit and 32 bit driver?

Answer (score 1):

You must install the NATIVE SQL 2005 driver to get access to Crystal Reports.

I don´t know exactly why, but Crystal Reports does not like other drivers than 2005 version - even the Crystal 2013.

In my applications I must setup Native 2005 Drivers to all my users to get all reports without the login screen (login is done programmatically).